# Difficulty applying a proof in Idris

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

I am attempting to prove a property over one of my defined data types as follows:

```
reverseProof' : (inputBlock : Block iType iSize iInputs)
          -> (ind : Fin rSize)
          -> (rInputs : Vect rSize Ty)
          -> (receiveBlock : Block rType rSize rInputs)
          -> (prf : index ind rInputs = iType)
          -> (newInsert : MaybeBlockty iType)
          -> (HVect (replaceAt ind (MaybeBlockty iType) (map MaybeBlockty rInputs))) 
          ->  (HVect (map MaybeBlockty rInputs))
```

In attempting to prove this I am trying to use an earlier proved fact that:

```
replaceAtProof' : (xs : Vect n a) 
           -> (i : Fin n)
           -> (f : a -> b) 
           -> ((index i xs) = x) 
           -> (replaceAt i (f x) (map f xs)) = (map f xs)
```

I was hoping that simply attempting to rewrite the appropriate expression in `reverseAtProof'` would achieve this, however when attempting to rewrite as follows:

```
reverseProof' inputBlock ind rInputs receiveBlock prf newInsert x = rewrite replaceAtProof' rInputs ind MaybeBlockty prf in x
```

I get the error as below:

```
When checking right hand side of reverseProof' with expected type HVect (map MaybeBlockty rInputs)

rewriting replaceAt ind
          (Maybe (len : Nat ** tyList : Vect len Ty ** Block iType len tyList))
          (Data.Vect.Vect n implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map MaybeBlockty rInputs) 

to 

           Data.Vect.Vect n implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map MaybeBlockty rInputs 

did not change type HVect (Data.Vect.Vect n implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map MaybeBlockty rInputs)
```

I read this error as saying that it could not apply the attempted rewrite as it could not find the specified pattern within `x`. This would appear to be because the compiler reduces the definition of

```
MaybeBlockty iType
```

to be

```
Maybe (len : Nat ** tyList : Vect len Ty ** Block iType len tyList)
```

:EDIT as is the definition of `MaybeBlockty`

Is there any way for me to prevent this from occurring so that the given rewrite will apply, or am I misreading the given error?

Comment: Could you paste the code in a gist in order to see what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rewrite` changes the type of the goal using the provided equality going from the left to the right. Since you need it to fit the type of `x`, it looks like your rewrite should go in the opposite direction: try `rewrite sym $ replaceAtProof' rInputs ind MaybeBlockty prf in x`

Comment: Thank you! that was indeed the problem. I misintepreted the order in which they applied.